# Windows Store App background music not looping and cant change the volume

Tags: c#, audio, windows-store-apps

i have project with many pages.

- i have 1 background music and every pages have couple audio.
- at mainpage, background music's volume must be %100
- when navigate to other pages background music volume going to decrease. (%60)
- and background audio have to loop.

in app.xaml.cs

```
public class MediaElementCommon
    {
        private static MediaElementCommon instance;
        private MediaElement _element = new MediaElement();

        private MediaElementCommon() { }

        public static MediaElementCommon Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new MediaElementCommon();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }

        public MediaElement GetElement()
        {
            return _element;
        }


public  async Task PlayBGAudio()
    {
        //this.volume = volume;
        var package = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current;
        var installedLocation = package.InstalledLocation;
        var storageFile = await installedLocation.GetFileAsync("Assets\\arkaplan.mp3");
        if (storageFile != null)
        {
            var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            MediaElementCommon.Instance.GetElement().SetSource(stream, storageFile.ContentType);
            //MediaElementCommon.Instance.GetElement().Volume =100;
            //MediaElementCommon.Instance.GetElement().IsLooping = true;
            MediaElementCommon.Instance.GetElement().Play();
            MediaElementCommon.Instance.GetElement().MediaEnded += new RoutedEventHandler(BGAudio_MediaEnded);

        }
    }

    private void BGAudio_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaElementCommon.Instance.GetElement().Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
        MediaElementCommon.Instance.GetElement().Play();
    }

public App()
    {
        PlayBGAudio();
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

    }
```

i changed the loop and volume properties but nothing changed.

Comment: [Volume is on a scale between 0 and 1, not 0 and 100.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.volume)

Comment: thanks for the reply. yes i know it scale between 0-1 i wrote %100 it means 1 :)

Comment: In your code though, you say `//MediaElementCommon.Instance.GetElement().Volume =100;` (Obviously commented), but are you implementing the switch properly?

Comment: i tried 0.6 and nothing changed. also tried looping part, didnt work either.

Comment: Try setting `RealTimePlayback' to 'true'. This also may not be the proper way to play background music. Would it be possible to change to using the method outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj841209.aspx)? You could have two copies of the music, one for 60% and one for 100% volume and just switch which one is playing based on the current view. You'd just have to change the Position on each view change, though I don't know how seamless that will be.

Comment: i set RealTimePlayback to true and no changes. background capable media stop playing when navigate to other page

Comment: The media stops playing when you navigate because the `MediaElement` is being unloaded. This is why you should use the `SystemMediaTransportControl`.